# Is there a way I can set a style for my disabled radio button when I'm using spans

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make my radio button square so I looked up some CSS to do so, which basically involved using spans and before and after. But now my client wants the radio buttons to be disabled and have a different style when disabled. Then I ran into a problem. Because I use spans I can't really style my radio button when it's disabled. Could I solve this with CSS? I could just switch the style with javascript but I'm looking for a CSS solution.

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #fbfbfb;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.radio-button
{
    display: none;
}

.radio[disabled] {
    display: none;
}

.radio-label  {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.radio-label .radio-span {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.radio-label .radio-span:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f0c8";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.radio-label .radio-span:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0px;
    transition: 300ms;
    opacity: 0;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f00c";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.radio-label .radio-button:checked+.radio-span:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* 
.radio-span needs to have this style when the radio button is disabled
{
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f04d";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 3px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-weight: 900;
} */
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/mycode.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label class="radio-label"><input id="toDisable" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="radio-button"> <span class="radio-span"> Male </span></label></br>
            <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="radio-button"> <span class="radio-span"> Female </span> </label></br>
            <label class="radio-label"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="other" class="radio-button"> <span class="radio-span"> Other </span></label> </br>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("toDisable").disabled = true;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your `span` are following siblings of the radio buttons the selector could be

```
.radio-button[disabled] + span {
  ...
}
```

using the `disabled` attribute on the `input` element

Comment: Changed it to .radio-button[disabled] + .radio-span:before but it did the trick! Thank you! I'll accept it asap